# Habilitando e desabilitando input

Tags: html, jquery

Criei um script para habilitar e desabilitar campos da minha pagina porém eles não estão rodando.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#EditarDados").click(function() {
    // habilita o campo 
    $("nome").prop("disabled", false);

  });

  $("#SalvarDados").click(function() {
    // desabilita o campo 
    $("nome").prop("disabled", true);

  });
});
```

```html
<button class="btn blue center-align" name="Salvar" id="SalvarDados">Salvar</button>
<button class="btn blue center-align" name="EditarDados" id="EditarDados">Editar Dados</button>
<input id="nome" name="nome" value="<?php echo $result['nm_nome'] ?>" type="text" disabled>
```

Comment: Qual navegador estas usando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está selecionando, através do jQuery, um elemento inexistente:

```
$("nome"); // Não existe no DOM
```

O seletor acima está selecionando isso:

```
<nome>...</nome>
```

Que provavelmente não é o que você deseja.

---

Se o seletor do campo que você deseja tornar `disabled` for `#nome`, você pode fazer assim:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#EditarDados").click(function () {
    $("#nome").prop("disabled", false);
  });

  $("#SalvarDados").click(function () {
     $("#nome").prop("disabled", true);
  });
});
```

Se você quiser selecionar através do atributo `name`, altere o `$("#nome")` por `$('[name="nome"]')`.

---

#### Prevenindo um evento padrão

Para prevenir um evento padrão, basta usar o método `.preventDefault()` do evento:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#EditarDados").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#nome").prop("disabled", false);
  });

  $("#SalvarDados").click(function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     $("#nome").prop("disabled", true);
  });
});
```

Para saber mais, queira ler:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: alterei porém quando aperto nos botões eles estão atualizando a pagina como se fossem um submit

Comment: Nesse caso, você deve prevenir o evento. Provavelmente você procura por `event.preventDefault()`. Eu editei a resposta. Veja acima.

Comment: vlw amigo me salvou

Comment: Vc sabe se tenho que alterar alguma propriedade para fazer desabilitar e habilitar um radio button ?

Comment: `disabled` é válido para qualquer tipo de input.

Comment: eu atribui assim

Comment: <input required name="Cd_sexo" value="Masculino" type="radio" id="rd_masculino" <?php echo $Result_sexoM ?> disabled="disabled"/>
                    <label for="rd_masculino">Masculino</label>
                    <input required name="Cd_sexo" type="radio" value="Feminino" id="rd_feminino" <?php echo $Result_sexoF ?> disabled="disabled"/>

Comment: porém quando tento desabilitar no javascript recebo uma mensagem dizendo que o Cd_sexo não existe

Comment: $("#Cd_sexo").prop("disabled", false);

Comment: Cara, acho que seja melhor você abrir uma pergunta nova pra isso. (Recomendo também deletar esses comentários fora do escopo da pergunta dessa página).

Answer (score 1):

Simplesmente o seu seletor esta errado:

```
$("nome").prop("disabled", false);
```

Deveria ser:

```
$("input[name=nome]").prop("disabled", false);
```

Os seletores no `jQuery` e no `document.querySeletor` são semelhantes aos usados no CSS, então quando usou apenas `$('nome')` o jQuery buscou por tags assim:

```
<nome></nome>
```

O seletor `input` buscará pelos inputs e a parte `[name=nome]` busca por atributo e por valor deste atributo.

Comment: alterei porém quando aperto nos botões eles estão atualizando a pagina como se fossem um submit